# Can @RabbitListener apply by condition

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want create a RabbitListener when a property is present, but @ConditionOnProperty cannot combine with @RabbitListener. Now I have a workaround below. Does it exist any better method?

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "pmc.multiple.hypervisor.reply.routerkey.kvm")
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer kvmReplyQueueConsumer() {
    return getSimpleMessageListenerContainer(environment
            .getProperty("pmc.multiple.hypervisor.reply.routerkey.kvm"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually try it? This works fine for me...

```
public static class ConditionalListener {

    @RabbitListener(queues="test.queue")
    public void listen(String foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}

@ConditionalOnProperty("foo.enabled")
@Bean
public ConditionalListener foo() {
    return new ConditionalListener();
}
```

When run with `-Dfoo.enabled=true` I get messages; otherwise the bean is not declared.

Comment: thanks, gary.
actually my condition is the queue wether exist, the property is the queue name.
in your code, when you say the bean not declare, does the simplemessagelistenercontainer not been created?

Comment: Correct, the bean is not declared, so no container is created - but this is a static property - you can't make it conditional on whether a queue exists in rabbitmq only on whether the property is present. In order to do that, allow the container to be created, but with `autoStartup=false` and then start the container in your code if the queue is present.

Answer (score 0):

you can using @Component and @Conditional for a single class